# Stripping .html extensions from requests and redirecting .html requests to .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, routes, web-config

I'm trying to point incoming HTTP requests with `.html` extensions to `.aspx` pages, and re-write the URLs in the browser such that neither the `.html` or `.aspx` extensions are displayed.

**Details:**

When a user requests, say, `localhost:123/lorem/ipsum.html`, I would return the `~/Views/lorem/ipsum.aspx` page.  The URL should look like `localhost:123/lorem/ipsum`.

One half of this is handled with the `AspNet.FriendlyUrls` package. In my `RouteConfig.cs` file, I have a set of rules like this:

`routes.MapPageRoute("Ipsum", "lorem/ipsum", "~/Views/lorem/ipsum.aspx");`

This makes sure that if a user sends a request off to `localhost:123/lorem/ipsum`, then the `.aspx` page loads with the correct URL nomenclature in the browser window.

I want to find out a way to extend this to incoming requests with `.html` at the end.  I tried adding another `RouteConfig.cs` rule to redirect users from `.html` to `.aspx` pages, with the hopes of using URL rewrites in the web config to display the URL correctly, but navigating to the page resulted in a 404:

`routes.MapPageRoute("Ipsum Html Redirect", "lorem/ipsum.html", "~/Views/lorem/ipsum.aspx");`

I'm very confused about the routing pipeline.  Do the Web.config rewrite/redirect rules take precedence over the `RouteConfig.cs` rules?  Is there a way to fix my problem by adding a `Web.config` rewrite or redirect rule, such that this works with my `RouteConfig.cs` rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RedirectingASPNETLegacyURLsToExtensionlessWithTheIISRewriteModule.aspx) blog link from Scott Hanselman to figure out a solution to the problem.  The solution was to add this code to the `Web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
         <rules>
             <rule name="extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="(.*)\.html$" />
                   <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
             </rule>
         </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```